# How can I get the output of an ssh command?

Tags: ruby, ssh

I'd like to programmatically check if someone has their SSH keys set up correctly for GitHub. I understand that I can use  `` `ssh -T git@github.com` `` in Ruby. However, I'd like to keep the ssh output in a variable.

My current code is:

```
github_response = `ssh -T git@github.com`
unless github_response.start_with?('Hi')
  puts 'Please set up your GitHub ssh keys'
end
```

`` `ssh -T git@github.com` `` outputs the response (starting with "Hi"). However the `github_response` variable is `nil`.

How can I assign the output of `` `ssh -T git@github.com` `` to `github_response`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example failed because the `Hi xxx! You've successfully authenticated....` message is not from stdout, but stderr.

```
> require 'open3'
=> true
> stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3('ssh -T git@github.com')
=> [#<IO:fd 8>, #<IO:fd 9>, #<IO:fd 11>, #<Thread:0x007f89ee1149a8 sleep>]

> stdout.gets
=> nil
> stderr.gets
=> "Hi halfelf! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add -v for verbose output, it will then dump much of the connection info to stdout. From that log you can scrape to find whether the server accepted any of the keys the ssh client offered